# Highcharts - Bar chart show full label on Y Axis

Tags: highcharts, label, yaxis

I am using formatting on the labels of the y-axis to display the label like 100,000 vs formatting of 100k that is automatically set on the charts.

However, this then squashes all the labels together with '...' at the end of each one - rather than showing the full value.

Is it possible to show the full label (i.e. 100,000) without the '...' at the end?

I've created a jfiddle with an example of what I am seeing (https://jsfiddle.net/htjb6wxb/5/)

```
yAxis: [{
labels: {
        format: '{value:,.0f} ',
        rotation: 0,
        y: 20,
        overflow: 'justify',
        padding: '5 px',
        align: 'center',
        style: {
            color: 'black',
            fontSize: '5 px',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
        }
    },
    }],
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to get your labels not to be cut off is to set `rotation` in `labels` and add a `marginRight` to `chart`

```
chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        marginRight: 50,
    },
```

---

```
 labels: {
            format: '{value:,.0f} ',
            rotation: -30,
            y: 20,
            overflow: 'justify',
            padding: '5 px',
            align: 'center',
            style: {
                color: 'black',
                fontSize: '5 px',
                fontWeight: 'normal',
            }
        },
        }],
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htjb6wxb/17/)